# Why is World Championship abbreviated as Worlds?

Tags: abbreviations

I have noticed that competitions such as

> European Championship, World Championship, National Championship

are commonly abbreviated as

> Euros, Worlds, Nationals

Is there a logic/grammatical rule for arriving at these specific short forms? Are apostrophes not usually used for contractions? For example, I have found [this site](http://www.gazetteer.co.uk/section3.htm) with abbreviations for British town names, which includes

> C'bridge for Cambridge

Comment: The pluralisation arises because the reference is to the multiple competitive matches taking place in preliminary heats and play-offs before two contestants finally battle it out in the European /  World / National Championship ***final***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [colloquialisms:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloquialism)

> A colloquial name or familiar name is a name or term commonly used to identify a person or thing in informal language, in place of another usually more formal or technical name.

The colloquialisms in your examples are plural in nature and therefore do not need an apostrophe. Apostrophes are used for contractions and possession. They are not typically used to pluralise abbreviations.

Because they are colloquialisms, by definition there is no particular rule for arriving at them.